# Java Syntax Error for Temperature Conversion Program Assignment: Line 3

Tags: java

I wrote the following code to run in repl.it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Convert{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    double farenheit;
    double celsius;

    System.out.print("Enter the temperature measurement in farenheit: 
");
    farenheit = reader.nextDouble();

    celsius = (farenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; 

    System.out.print("The equivalent in celsius is: ");
    System.out.println(celsius);
  }
}
```

I cannot get it to run unless I switch "Convert" in line three to "Main".

Why is that? I thought the syntax was public class *name of program*. Shouldn't that work? Do I need to use something besides repl.it, such as an IDE like BlueJ or JGRASP to do such work?

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Be precise. Post the exact commands and errors you get.

Comment: If it's the default startup, you're in a file called `Main.java`, in which the only public class can be `Main`. With the caveat that it probably *expects* there to be a `Main.java` so it has a known entry point. So you'd need to re-structure your code somewhat.

Comment: Just add a new file called Convert.java in the bar on the left, put your Convert class in that, and it should run just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a class as `public` then your class name and file name must be the same.

In your case your class name is `Convert` which means you either have to have it in a file named `Convert.java`, or remove the `public` attribute.

Comment: Please consider using complete words and punctuation. I have edited your post.

Comment: If I were to remove the public attribute, what would I replace it with? I am assuming there are options.